# SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON with EF Core 6.0 not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, identity

My business scenario is: we are trying to move from one vendor to our own solution. Currently, we are building the solution.

Building our own solution requires the identity column for `TicketId` to auto incremented.

We are also importing the data from the vendor using vendor's API, which has an `TicketId` already assigned which we want to keep.

For this we need to insert the `TicketId` manually to keep track of the Id between our database and vendor's database. How do I do that. I tried the following and doesn't seem to work.

I looked at this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/value-generation#inserting-explicit-values-into-identity-columns)

Would appreciate, if anyone can propose a solution or let me know what I'm not doing correctly.

Not sure whether Sequences will help in the process.

I have a table called Ticket with the following

```
public partial class Ticket
{
      public long TicketId { get; set; }
      ...
}

public void Configure([NotNull] EntityTypeBuilder<Ticket> builder)
{
     builder.HasKey(_ => _.TicketId);

     builder.Property(e => e.TicketId).ValueGeneratedNever();
     ....
}
```

and in the Service, I'm trying to save the data as follows

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Corporate.Ticket ON");
dbContext.SaveChanges();
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Corporate.Ticket Off");
```

This always throws an error

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details. Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ticket' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

In the entity, I had tried to set

```
builder.Property(e => e.TicketId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

as well as

```
builder.Property(e => e.TicketId).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Comment: I notice that in your code you don't open the connection like the example in the article you cited.  Have you tried that or did you just omit that from the code you've shown?

Comment: Add a separate TicketId column and keep an actual db native Identity column. IMO ID columns should never be used for biz rule hacks like this.

Comment: As mentioned above, open connection. EF Core closes connection after each request, if there is no transaction or connection is not opened manually.

Comment: I was able to get it working. The issue is there is another child table which has identity that was creating the exception.

So, instead of one single unit of work I save the Ticket table first and get the id and update the child table and then save.

Thanks for the input